# 2つのMySQLのスキーマが一致してるか確認する方法

Tags: mysql

既存の Rails マイグレーションを別の環境のMySQLで実行したので
当然一致してると思うんですが上長にエビデンスを出す必要があります

全テーブルのスキーマを表示するようなSQLってあるんでしょうか
schema_name というのは取得できるみたいなのですが
全テーブルの全カラムのタイプやサイズ、インデックス情報、FK制約
等を取得したいです

文字列として取得できれば diff をとるだけでいいのですが
簡単な方法はありますでしょうか

Comment: DESCでテーブルを指定すると列名や型などの情報がとれそうです。全テーブルとなると、ストアードプロシジャやshスクリプトでループをまわす必要があります。Oracle(11gや12c)ではよくお世話になっていましたが、MySQLでも使えそうです。※実機で試していないのでコメントとしています

Answer (score 2, accepted):

両方の環境にアクセスできる状態であれば
Oracleが提供しているMysqlUtilitiesの中にmysqldiffというツールがあります。
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-utilities-1.5-en/mysqldiff.html

もし「別環境で接続できない」や「ツールが導入できない」ということであればダンプを作成して比較するがもっとも良いと思います。
mysqldumpがバックアップ用のツールですが、最も使いやすいと思います。
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/mysqldump.html

スキーマだけを取得する場合は以下のように記述すればスキーマのみ取得できます。

```
mysqldump --no-data DATABASE_NAME > DATABASE_NAME.sql
```

その他にもオプションがいろいろありますので、そちらは公式リファレンスを確認してください。

Comment: dump コマンドでやったんですが AUTO INCREMENT の値が違うのはともかくなぜか片方だけが using BTREE というのがでてしまっていました。ともかくエビデンスにはできました！